# How do I return a Bitmap type?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have this method that is supposed to take a screenshot and return the image to the calling method.

```
public static Bitmap TakeScreenshot(int x, int y, int height, int width)
{
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, height, width);
    Bitmap bitmap;

    using (bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(x, y), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        }
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to save the picture:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MyClass.TakeScreenshot(0, 0, 200, 200);
bitmap.Save(@"C:\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Then I get an error at the save-method.

> ArgumentException was unhandled.
>   Parameter is not valid.

It works fine if I try to save it inside the method like this:

```
public static Bitmap TakeScreenshot(int x, int y, int height, int width)
{
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, height, width);

    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(x, y), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        }
        bitmap.Save(@"c:\begin.tiff", ImageFormat.Tiff);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried saving as a Jpeg inside your second method? Right now your passing and failing code are trying to save in two different formats.

Comment: I know and should probably have corrected that to avoid the confusion. But it will save in the same format in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first example, the `Bitmap` has been disposed via the `using` statement, you are then saving afterwards.

In the second example, you are saving before the disposal.

All you should need to do is not wrap the bitmap in a `using` statement,  Instead, either leave it for the garbage collector, or call `.Dispose()` after you've saved it.

Personally, for items that implement the `IDisposable` interface, I tend to make sure `Dispose` is called, unless my usage dictates keeping it alive.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to think about that when implementing the IDisposable interface.

Answer (score 3):

The `Bitmap` is being disposed prior to being returned - that is to say, you're returning an `IDisposable` object that has already had `Dispose` called:

```
using (bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
{
}
//using block makes sure Dispose is called when
//out of scope so this bitmap is no more
return bitmap;
```

If you want to use the bitmap outside of scope of the method, then you'll have to "release ownership" (create it, but don't be responsible for destroying within that scope) and allow the caller to manage it, and dispose it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're declaring and accessing the Bitmap object outside the using block, then don't use a using block :)   I would have coded it like this:

```
public static Bitmap TakeScreenshot(int x, int y, int height, int width)
{
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, height, width);
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(x, y), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: You know you're a programmer when you see someone using using using in a sentence and you know what they mean.